# How to separate character value to divide by regex in matrix

Tags: r, regex, string, split, stringr

**Data example :**

```
X <- as.matrix(c("2019.01.01 (TUE) A STADIUM       [spectator : 4000]", "2019.01.01 (TUE) C STADIUM       [spectator : 3600]", "2018.01.02 (WED) B STADIUM       [spectator : 2800]", "2019.01.02 (WED) D STADIUM       [spectator : 3500]"))
X
     [,1]                                                  
[1,] 2019.01.01 (TUE) A STADIUM       [spectator : 4000]
[2,] 2019.01.01 (TUE) C STADIUM       [spectator : 3600]
[3,] 2018.01.02 (WED) B STADIUM       [spectator : 2800]
[4,] 2019.01.02 (WED) D STADIUM       [spectator : 3500]
```

I want to separate this data frame 3 or 4 column. Like this:

```
         Day Day2    STADIUM   Spectator                                    
1 2019.01.01 TUE   A STADIUM    4000
2 2019.01.01 TUE   C STADIUM    3600
3 2018.01.02 WED   B STADIUM    2800
4 2019.01.02 WED   D STADIUM    3500
```

**What i have tried** : 
`str_split` returns list. So i used `str_split_fixed`. It's required n value. I assigned n = 4. But it separate punctuation mark forward.

```
str_split_fixed(X, n = 4, '[[:punct:]]')
     [,1]   [,2] [,3]  [,4]                                     
[1,] "2019" "01" "01 " "TUE) A STADIUM       [spectator : 4000]"
[2,] "2019" "01" "01 " "TUE) C STADIUM       [spectator : 3600]"
[3,] "2018" "01" "02 " "WED) B STADIUM       [spectator : 2800]"
[4,] "2019" "01" "02 " "WED) D STADIUM       [spectator : 3500]"
```

Comment: What about `str_match(X, "^(\\S+)\\s+\\(([A-Z]+)\\)\\s+(.*?)\\s+\\[spectator\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\]$")`? You could then get the values from `[,2]`, `[,3]`, `[,4]` and `[,5]` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::extract` by defining capture groups to extract

```
tidyr::extract(data.frame(X), X, into = c("Day", "Day2", "Stadium", "Spectator"), 
           regex = "(.*)\\((.*)\\).*([A-Z]+ STADIUM).*spectator : (\\d+)")

#         Day  Day2   Stadium Spectator
#1 2019.01.01   TUE A STADIUM      4000
#2 2019.01.01   TUE C STADIUM      3600
#3 2018.01.02   WED B STADIUM      2800
#4 2019.01.02   WED D STADIUM      3500
```

We define 4 capture groups here.

1) Starts from beginning of the text till an opening round bracket is encountered.

2) The text between opening and closing round brackets.

3) One or more character from `[A-Z]` followed by word `"STADIUM"`

4) number after word `"spectator"`.

Comment: If it's not english(other country's language), what i can use instead of [A-Z] . Also [:graph:]. It returns na value in real data. The front part works in real data.

Comment: @Sangwonkim Try `regex = "(.*)\\((.*)\\).*(\\w+ STADIUM).*spectator : (\\d+)")`. What is `[:graph:]` ? I haven't used that in my answer.

Comment: Ah okay, your answer is correct. I'll find out a little more about what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
X <- c("2019.01.01 (TUE) A STADIUM       [spectator : 4000]", "2019.01.01 (TUE) C STADIUM       [spectator : 3600]", "2018.01.02 (WED) B STADIUM       [spectator : 2800]", "2019.01.02 (WED) D STADIUM       [spectator : 3500]")
Dat <- read.table(text=X)[c(1:3, 7)]
names(Dat) <- c("Day", "Day2", "STADIUM", "Spectator")
Dat$Spectator <- sub("]", "", Dat$Spectator, fixed = TRUE)
Dat$Day2 <- substr(Dat$Day2, 2, 4)
Dat
# > Dat
#          Day Day2 STADIUM Spectator
# 1 2019.01.01  TUE       A      4000
# 2 2019.01.01  TUE       C      3600
# 3 2018.01.02  WED       B      2800
# 4 2019.01.02  WED       D      3500
```